# Access different Implementation/Component with one of same bean in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, components, implementation, profile

```
@Configuration
@Profile("live")
public class LiveProfileConfig{

    @Bean
    public BaseInterface commonInterface(){
        return new LiveComponent();
    }

}

@Configuration
@Profile("test")
public class TestProfileConfig{

    @Bean
    public BaseInterface commonInterface(){
        return new TestComponent();
    }
}
```

Now, in Main Spring boot application, I set the "live" profile as following

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {LiveProfileConfig.class, TestProfileConfig.class},loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@ActiveProfiles(value="live")
```

Then call one of implmentation to use component according active profile,

```
@Service
public class AnotherImpl implements AnotherInterface {

    @Autowired
    BaseInterface commonInterface;  
}
```

Now, I want to access one of component methods (i.e. LiveComponent / TestComponent) based on active profile.

It works in JUnit test but while I try to run it with Spring Boot Application it gives me below error.

> required a single bean, but 2 were found, Consider marking one of the
>   beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or
>   using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed

Any help?

Comment: That's not possible, if only `live` profile is active then spring would ignore the `test` profile bean. Check the value of `spring.profiles.active` property by using `System.getProperty()`. It should have expected profile value.

Comment: Yes, I want to do same, like when live profile is active then access only LiveComponent methods.